# Roots, polynomials and equality breaking

Tags: roots, fake-proofs

Suppose I have

$$
z=(a+ib)\implies z^2=(a+ib)^2\implies z=\pm(a+ib)
$$

But if I do this instead:

$$
\begin{align}
z&=a+bi\\
\implies z^2&=a^2-b^2+2iab\\
&=a(2a+2ib-a)-b^2\\
&=a(2z-a)-b^2\\
z^2-2az+a^2+b^2&=0\\
&\implies z=a\pm ib
\end{align}
$$

Why the contradiction?

Comment: Your second calculation is hard to follow.  Between lines $2$ and $3$, are you not $\textit {assuming}$ that $z=a+ib$?

Comment: If z= a+ ib then $z^2= a^2+ 2iab+ (ib)^2a= a^2- b^2+ 2iab$.

Comment: @lulu I start with $z=a+bi$, then I square it to get $z^2=a^2-b^2+2iab$. I added an edit

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay But you're **not** starting with $z=a+bi$, you're starting with $z^{2} = (a+bi)^{2}$. *Your edit changes everything, now both versions are give false solutions*

Comment: But you don't know that $z=a+bi$.  More broadly, you can always get "false" solutions by squaring "true" solutions. If I start with $x=1$ I can square to get $x^2=1$ which implies that $x=\pm 1$.  So what?  Squaring introduced the false solution.

Comment: @lulu crystal clear, thanks.

Comment: Note that both statements are now actually true; if $z = a+ib$ then you do have that $z = $(either) $\pm(a+ib)$, as well as that $z = $(either)$a \pm ib$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no contradiction.  In the first derivation, you have shown that if $z=a+ib$, then either $z=a+ib$ or $z=-a-ib$.  That is true, because $z=a+ib$.

In the second, you have shown that if $z=a+ib$, then either $z=a+ib$ or $z=a-ib$.  That is true, because $z=a+ib$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no contradiction: $z=a+ib$ implies both $z=\pm (a+ib)$ and $z=a\pm ib$.  To be clear, a statement like $z=\pm(a+ib)$ in this context means "$z=a+ib$ or $z=-(a+ib)$".  If $z=a+ib$, then certainly any "or" statement where one of the options is $z=a+ib$ is also true, and that applies to both $z=\pm(a+ib)$ and $z=a\pm ib$.